# Mellin transform of powers of Bessel function?

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, mellin-transform

How can I evaluate the following Mellin transform
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s - 1}\operatorname{K}_{0}\left(x\right)^{n}\,{\rm d}x\quad\mbox{for positive integers}\ n\ ?
$$
For $n = 1,2$, it is expressible in terms of Gamma functions.

Does this hold for all powers, or is the answer expressed in terms of different functions? What about for specific cases $n = 3, 4, 5$?

Comment: $n = 3,\ 4$ involves the $Meijer\ \operatorname{G}\mbox{-}Function$

Comment: for `n=4` is: $\frac{1}{8} \pi  G_{4,4}^{3,3}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,1,1,\frac{s+1}{2} \\
 \frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$ where **G** is MeijerG function.